# $\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}2^{-\lvert j\rvert}=4$?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Am I right with
$$\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}2^{-\lvert j\rvert}=4?$$

Idea:

Write the sum as
$$
\sum_{j=-\infty}^{0}2^j+\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}2^{-j}=2\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}=2\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=4.
$$

Answer (score 7):

You've included the $j=0$ term twice.

Fix that, and your approach is the right one.